# Image Asset menu item not listed in Android Studio Dolphin ver 2021.3.1 patch 1

Tags: android-studio

[image]

I read somewhere that image asset should be available with Android Studio Dolphin ver 2021.3.1 patch 1.
But I still don't see it. See image.

Expected to see image asset, but it's not displayed in Android Studio Dolphin ver 2021.3.1 patch.